# Update single column field in table using Hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to update the single value in table (without updating any others) by using Hibernate.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void updateUser(User userDetails){
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User u set u.balance = :balanceValue where u.userId = :userIdValue AND c.userType = :userTypeValue");
query.setParameter("balanceValue", userDetails.getBalance());
query.setParameter("userIdValue", userDetails.getUserId());
query.setParameter("userTypeValue", userDetails.getUserType());
query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Please note that all parameters I am inserting are String. Columns u.userType and u.userId are composite keys.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException. Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   "IN".

I have spent hours on understanding what is wrong with this query. I am using "User" entity for save, update criteria (writing all fields) and delete row without any problems. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What was the other exception, the one caused by this SQLException? What database are you connecting to? What are your hibernate settings?

Comment: Try after setting show_sql true which will give you the sql to identify issue.

Comment: You're not showing the real code. This query is invalid: what is `c` in `c.userType`. You're also hiding the full stack trace of the exception, where the SQL query is displayed. So we can't help.